# PHP Time not correct in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add a sort of timestamp to a field in my database using: `$today = date("d-m-Y | H:i:s");`. Which inputs the current date and time in the database.

But for some reason the time is incorrect. It's off by 2 hours. At this moment it's 15:32 here and it inputs 13:32:16 in the database.

I've been looking everywhere to change this. Looked if there is some sort of `offset` to add +2. But nothing.

I've added

`define('TIMEZONE', 'Europe/Amsterdam ');
date_default_timezone_set(TIMEZONE);`

to the script but that didn't do anything. Is there any way I can get this to work? I don't have access to the SQL server (or PHP.ini). I found [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/synchronize-php-mysql-timezone-configuration/) article but this didn't help me.

Comment: Can you run `date` or your other server-specific time command on the server?

Comment: Unrelated, but you can use `date("d-m-Y | H:i:s")`.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: apart from your timezone issue: why not store your data in a column of type DATETIME? It opens possibility to for example sort on it

Comment: What @castis is meaning is that instead of `$today = date("d-m-Y".' | '."H:i:s");` , you can use: `date("d-m-Y | H:i:s");`

Comment: @IvoP If I do that the date is not correct it will show `2017-07-18` and not `18-07-2017`

Comment: @WouterVeen Yes. Thats no problem. It returns the date and time.

Comment: Thats why it was offtopic but ontopic can you print the current timezone that php is using? `date_default_timezone_get()`

Comment: @Jay-oh Output `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` before and after you set the timezone. The server may not allow you to adjust the timezone. Keep in mind that MySQL runs off the server's time and PHP will adjust based on the timezone in the `php.ini`.

Comment: @WouterVeen here is de print from the current timezone: `date_default_timezone_set: UTC`

Comment: @Jay-oh  "If I do that the date is not correct it will show 2017-07-18 and not 18-07-2017". That's what you have php's formating tools for. "18-07-2017" is while sorting greater than "01-08-2017". So store it in a format that's made for that purpose.

Comment: @Daerik No go. That didn't change it. unfortunately

Comment: And what if you do `INSERT INTO table (datecolumn) VALUES ( NOW() );`

Comment: Well call me silly!  
apart from your timezone issue: why not store your data in a column of type DATETIME? It opens possibility to for example sort on it – Ivo P that worked? I't didn't before...

Comment: @Jay-oh I'm not trying to give you a solution. I wanted you to realize that you are not able to change the timezone from UTC. If you wanted to manually adjust it, you'll want to offset it like: `date('d-m-Y | H:i:s', strtotime('+1 Hours'))`.

Comment: @Daerik: So, no offset for me. I'll have to leave the time behind me. Because of this issue with the timezone?

Comment: Does this problem involve your database? So far it only seems to be a PHP issue. What happens when you try WillParky93's approach.  If it is only about entering the current time into your database. What says `SELECT NOW(): ` when executed on your database? Does it then show the correct time (apart from the date not formated in the Dutch form you prefer?

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help. The problem was solved using a `TEXT` row in the database and this code (with the help of Daerik) `$today = date('d-m-Y | H:i:s',strtotime("$date + 2 hours"));`. It was only a PHP issue :)

Comment: question: will this still work in November? As daylightsaving / zomertijd ends somewhere in the last days of October and we will be only 1 hour ahead of UTC

Comment: Well, then I just have to change it again :D No biggie. It's not THAT important but I just wanted it to show for different users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the timezone of your server and the format you want it in. I can't help but recommend using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) function for this as it's just so easy to use.

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam');
$datetime = new DateTime(date(), new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$datetime->setTimezone($tz);
$today = $datetime->format("d-m-Y | H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

please Don't save it as the Unix Timestamp (which `strtotime()` outputs), but as "2017-07-18 20:30:59" into the DATETIME column.